# Twig - Long Text with more button

Tags: drupal, twig

Working in a template in Drupal 8:

1. I have a (long) text - Variable and want to find the first occurrence of `</p>` and replace it with `</p><div class="collapse" id="viewdetails">`.
2. I also wan’t to find the last occurrence `</p>` and replace it with `</p></div><p><button data-target="#viewdetails" data-toggle="collapse">More.. »</button></p>`.

The idea is to trim a long text and add a `more` button.

Is this possible with Twig?

Thank's a lot

Comment: Probably better to do it in a preprocess function or a custom formatter.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Will check this out.
I'm new to Twig, my thought was to do it in some way with 'slice' - 'slice' from position '0' to the first occurrence of '</p>'; and 'slice' the last occurrence of '</p>'.
Having these 2 slices in variables, I could then add the wished 'more-button-code', and finally put all the text together.